# Configure jsr-305 annotations for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, findbugs, spotbugs

I have configured Eclipse as seen in the screenshot.
[image]

However I get no errors for this code:

```
  @Nonnull public static Object test(@CheckForNull Object t) {
    return t;
  }
```

When I run spotbugs on this code I get:

> t must be non-null but is marked as nullable

How to get Eclipse to work with those annotations?

Version is: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)

NB. not sure if it's relevant but I'm using eclipse with the lombok plugin

Comment: Did you add and use the spotbugs eclipse plugin? Because eclipse own its own does not recognize jsr-305. (which is dead by the way). And I am curious in which section did you configure those settings? **Update** Interesting ...I found it in the compiler\Errors/warnings section. I would say you need to add the jsr-305.jar to the eclipse classpath so that the annotations are available for eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

You have configured it correctly. You have to add the JSR-305.jar dependency to your project to make it work. But you must have done that already since the imports are correctly resolved, right? I have created a testproject and correctly see an error:

[image: Showing eclipse null error]

If I remove the `@Nonnull` annotation the error goes away:

[image: Everything is fine]

Some infos can be found [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis).

Comment: Can you share you Eclipse version details (platform and jdt)? Did you configure it in any special way?

Comment: @JakubBochenski I did the configuration like you did in your screenshot. My eclipse version is 2019-12 (4.14.0) and Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Comment: I have a slightly more recent version and I'm using a different base distribution. Not a big chance but maybe it matters